# Javascript - Trying to filter array with properties

Tags: javascript, html, filter

Here is some example code I am stuck. I think it is something to do with the property of the array any guidance? I am looking to filter the array using the league property.

```
<script>
var teams = [
{name: "newcastle", league: "Premiership"},
{name: "Hull", league: "League 1"},
{name: "Sunderland", league: "League 1"},
{name: "Arsenal", league: "Premiership"}];

var filterLeague = teams.filter(function (teams) {
 return (teams.league === "Premiership");
});

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = filterLeague;

</script>
```

Comment: `filterLeauge` is a array. why are you putting it as `innerHTML`?

Comment: consider running it through a debugger to see what happens...

Comment: What is the output you're getting vs. what you expect?

Comment: To add to these comments you should also think about how you might be able to include `.map()` to show your output.

Comment: Your filter is working okay: `[{name: "newcastle", league: "Premiership"}, {name: "Arsenal", league: "Premiership"}]`. Putting the result in `innerHTML` looks like the issue...

Comment: Thank you for the help, seems the issue is with me creating the output! Thanks for the guidance on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter is working fine but what it returns is an array so adding it `innerHTML` isn't going to work out so well.

There are a few ways you could create the output depending on what you want to do. You could stringify your array as the other answers suggest. Or you can use `.map()` to iterate over each result appending it as a new html element.

```js
var teams = [
{name: "newcastle", league: "Premiership"},
{name: "Hull", league: "League 1"},
{name: "Sunderland", league: "League 1"},
{name: "Arsenal", league: "Premiership"}];

teams
.filter(function (teams) {
 return (teams.league === "Premiership");
})
.map(function(team) {
  var ul = document.getElementById('map-output');
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = team.name;
  ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<ul id="map-output"></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you this resolved this issue and demonstrated a way to create an output.

Comment: No worries. And if you'd like a more in-depth tutorial of using Map/Filter/Reduce I'd suggest this RxJS tutorial http://reactivex.io/learnrx/

Answer (score 4):

the filter result is Array of objects. you need covert it to some kind of string in order to display in a DOM element

```
<div id='output'></div>
<script>
var teams = [
{name: "newcastle", league: "Premiership"},
{name: "Hull", league: "League 1"},
{name: "Sunderland", league: "League 1"},
{name: "Arsenal", league: "Premiership"}];

var filterLeague = teams.filter(function (teams) {
 return (teams.league === "Premiership");
});

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filterLeague);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = filterLeague
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filterLeague);
```